# No records shown when using select statement, db_datareader

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, roles, user-roles

I have the role `db_datareader` in SQL server 2008 and I can view all the tables in the object explorer. When I try to write a `SELECT` statement the query has no problems with executing but I can't see any records. There are just some headers and an empty box with no data.

I know that there is nothing wrong with the query. I've also tried with plain `Select * from table` and also clicking on that `select top 1000 rows`, still the same problems occurs.

Why is this? I read somewhere that I should have the `db_datawriter` role as well but I don't want to have the ability to delete things etc.

Help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: How do you know there's nothing wrong with the query? If this was a permissions issue, you would get an error message and not an empty result set and so it sounds like there are simply no records being found

Comment: thank you for your comment. I dont think its anything wrong with the query becouse ive also tried "Select * from [table]" and "select top 1000 rows", those should always work? The results is the same though

Comment: Those queries would return no records if there are just no records in the table though. Like I said, if it was a permissions issue, you would get an error.

Comment: Check that your table actually has records to retrieve. as @PaulHunt said, No permission related errors suggests no records if the standard `SELECT TOP 1000` query also returns zero results.

Comment: What is the result of `Select COUNT(*) from [table]`?

Comment: Are you connected to correct server or database? ;)

Comment: I entered the query from another user which is db_owner and it worked.

Comment: are you trying to query _system_ or _user-defined_ table?